# Reinstaling Windows 7 after dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have old laptop which I need to sell. Laptop runs Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 along.
I need to reinstall back just Windows 7 bacause of customer wishes. But I have a problem. When put cd with Win 7 and press F12 to call boot menu, it dont load, it just overides cd boot and takes me to Ubuntu purple screen which system I want to start up. To be clear, I want to format whole disk with existing dual boot (Wind7 and Ubuntu) and just install clean Windows 7 to be ready for customer. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that F12 is the boot menu key?

Comment: Yes, it is on Acer Aspire 5472

Answer (score 0):

do this steps

1. restart your pc and press f2
2. go to boot section
3. enable usb
4. save
5. restart
6. press f12
7. select usb
8. delete all the partitions
9. install a fresh copy of windows 7
10. done

Comment: What's wrong with cd??

Comment: make a bootable pendrive and try it , if you doubt ...

Comment: I have already usb bootable installation...tried with usb, same problem.

Comment: press f2, then go to the "main section tab" and see if "boot menu is enabled" and then go to " boot section tab" and just arrange the list so that the cd rom comes to the top....and your laptop would automatically detect windows cd or you would be able to go to the boot menu by pressing f12